# Set Specified date 1 Minute equals 3 months

Tags: c#, datetime, timer

```
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);  

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);  
         timer1.Interval = 60000;

         timer1.Enabled = true;
         timer1.Start();
         newDate.AddMonths(+3);
         lblDate.Text = newDate.ToString();
    }
```

Using C#, why does this timer not work? I want to be able to set a date, (01/01/2013) and for each minute that proceeds to equal three months

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me, but it looks like maybe you need to use `newDate = newDate.AddMonths(+3);`.  Remember, `DateTime` is immutable, so you can't change its value, you have to re-assign it.

Comment: Thank you! it works but for some reason it adds 3 months on the first "cycle" and then adds more and more and eventually starts adding decades; do you know what is wrong?

Comment: The reason it adds more and more as time goes on is that for each tick you added *another* event handler. On the first tick, the date got incremented by 3 months and you added another handler. So on the next tick it got incremented by 3 months *twice*, and another handler was added. So for each tick you ended up adding N*3 months, where N was the number of minutes the timer had been running.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @dbaseman 's comment, I think part of your problem may lie in that you are trying to add an event listener inside of your event listener. Try this:

```
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
timer1.Interval = 60000;  
timer1.Enabled = true;
timer1.Tick += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>{
     newDate = newDate.AddMonths(+3);
     lblDate.Text = newDate.ToString();
}
timer1.Start();
```

Or if you don't like Lambdas

```
void Init(){
    DateTime newDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
    timer1.Interval = 60000;  
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick)
    timer1.Start();
}

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
     newDate = newDate.AddMonths(+3);
     lblDate.Text = newDate.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I used the second method and it seems to work perfectly :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried the code out (the second way) and for some reason a change in "timer.Interval" does not cause a change in how fast 3 months are added, 3 months are added consistently at the same pace; can you please help?

Comment: You may have to Stop and then Start the timer again.

Comment: where would I put that though?